# Single virtual tomcat application which serves multiple contexts

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, web

I have multiple clients:

- client 1 - 40 users
- client 2 - 50 users
- client 3 - 60 users

And I have a web application that is supposed to serve all the clients.
The application is deployed into Tomcat. Each client has it's own database.

What I want to implement is the single web application instance which servers all the clients. The client (and the database to connect to) is identified by the context path from the URL.

I.e. I imply the following scenario:

1. Some user requests the http://mydomain.com/client1/
2. Tomcat invokes a single instance of my application (no matter which context is requested)
3. My application processes the rest of the request thinking that it's deployed to /client1 context path, i.e. all redirect or relative URLs should be resolved against http://mydomain.com/client1/

When the client 2 requests the http://mydomain.com/client2/, I want my application (the same instance) now process it just like if it was deployed to /client2 context path.

Is this possible with Tomcat?

Comment: It would be really easier and much safer to deploy the same app (configure differently) three times, each with its own config and context path. The way you're doing it, someone from client1 could easily have access to the data of client2. You would end up reimplementing what Tomcat implements for you.

Comment: Well, the application is pretty big, and of course I have not 3 clients but many many more. I'm just trying to reduce memory consumptions and prevent loading of the same app many times.

Comment: I can see the desire to reduce memory consumption, specially if the app is very big. However, it seems to me that the design of it has drawn it into a corner. The best approach has always been to 1) either have three distinctly configured deployments (as JB Nizet said) or 2) have three physically distinct container processes each hosting a single, distinctly configured deployment. Which one is better depends on the application and JEE container. You are trying to implement app/container isolation by hand. Many ways to go *"ZOMG! SNAFU"*, so proceed with caution if you must go down this path.

Comment: Memory is cheap. Software engineers (and lawyers) are not :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application has to do this not tomcat.  Now you could deploy your application in three new contexts (client1, client2, client3) with slightly different configuration for the database, and if you are careful to use relative URLs (ie don't do things like /images) then you can do this without changes.  This is the transparent way of making your application reusable in that your application is unaware of the global picture that you have 3 different instances of itself running.  That means you can easily deploy more or more without having to change your application.  You just configure a new instance and go.  This only requires you don't use absolute URLs to resources.  Using ServletContext.getContextPath() and using .. in your CSS, scripts, etc is helpful as well here.

Probably one of the biggest advantages working this way is that your app doesn't care about global concerns.  Because its not involved in those decisions you can run 3 instances on one tomcat server, or if one client needs more scaling they can be moved to their own tomcat server easily.  By making your app portable it has forced you to deal with how to install your app in any environment.  This is a pillar of horizontal scaling which your situation could very much take advantage being you can split your DB data without having to rejoin them (huge advantage).  The option you asked about doesn't force you to deal with this so when the time comes to deal with it it will be painful.

The other option is more involved and requires significant changes to your application to handle this.  This is by parsing the incoming URL and pulling out the name of the client then using that name to look up in a configuration file for the database that should be used for that client.  SpringMVC can handle things like extracting variables from URL paths.  Then making sure you render everything back to them so it points to their portion of the URL.  This probably would require a lot of the same requirements as the first.  You can use absolute URLs for things like javascript, CSS, and images, but URLs to your app would have to be rewritten at runtime so that it is relative to the requesting client.  The benefit is that your only load your application once.

Just as an aside, if you host your CSS, Javascript, images on a CDN in production then both of these options must be relative URL aware.  Upsides and downsides to using CDNs as well.

While that sounds good it might not be a good thing because all clients use the same version of the app.  Also if you bring down a the app to fix client1 to do maintenance it affects all clients.  If you think you'll have to do customization per client then this option will get messy quick.  Upgrading a single client means all clients must upgrade and depending on your business model this might not be compatible.  Furthermore, I'm not entirely sure you'll save a lot of memory either running only a single version of the application because most apps only take up 10MB of code loaded.  A vast majority of the memory is in the VM and processing requests, and using a single Tomcat instance means you share the VM.  And with 1 or 3 instances running you still have the same number of requests.  You might see a difference of 30-100MBs which in todays world is chump change, and all of those other concerns aren't addresses if you choose to save only a couple of MB.

Essentially there are facilities in Tomcat to aid you in doing this (multiple contexts), but its mostly up to your application to handle this especially if its a single instance.